# Boundness of the solutions for $x'' +cx'+\sin(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know when the solutions of:

$x'' +cx'+\sin(x) = 0$

are bounded in $[t_0,+\infty[$ depending on $c$.

This is a case of second order differential equation  that can be interpreted as an oscillator where there is friction, represented by $c$.

The usual techniques fail for this example since $\sin(x)$ is not coercive

Comment: for a fixed $c$, it depends on initial conditions. even for $c=0$. Now, the point $(0,0)$ is a fixed point of the system (position $0$, speed $0$). So perhaps you are asking about initial points not too far from these?

Comment: I did some testing with http://www.bluffton.edu/homepages/facstaff/nesterd/java/slopefields.html   It seems to depend mostly on the sign of $c$ if $c$ is nonzero

Comment: I would still be looking for a cualitative reasoning and not directly integrating the equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\dot x \ddot x + c \dot x ^2+\dot x \sin x = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(\dot x)^2+c(\dot x)^2 = \frac{d}{dt}\cos(x)
$$

Now $(\dot x)^2 + c \int (\dot x)^2 dt = \cos(x) + C_0$

hence if $c > 0 \Rightarrow (\dot x)^2 \le \cos x + C_0$

Comment: Attached additional conclusions.

Comment: Ok, so if X has bounded derivative then it is bounded? And if $c=0$ then how would you reason?  (I'd say that the case c < 0 can be handled from here...

Comment: Solving $\dot x = \sqrt{\cos x+C_0}$ with null initial conditions,we have

$$
x = 2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{(C_0+1) \tanh \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-C_0^2} t\right)}{\sqrt{1-C_0^2}}\right)
$$

This function is bounded for $C_0^2 < 1$

Comment: Just to check, your last comment addresses the $c=0$ case?

Comment: If $c=0$ the answer is trivial because the differential equation has closed solution composed by Jacobi functions.